# File is present but error : "no such table"

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite

I have a problem in my app and I don't know where it comes from ...

So I add my file to my project [image: Look at Him !] The on highlighted !

But when I want to init and select in my table I have an error :

`no such table`

I'm pretty sure the table is here beceause in my terminal I got this : [image]

And I do the same request in my code :

`tableData = [sqlManager getList:@"SELECT name_fr FROM info_max"];`

sqlManager works with the 3 other files ..

I use this to init

```
-(id)initDatabase:(NSString*)dbName {

    if (self = [super init]) {
        //Nom de la base de données
        databaseName = dbName;

        //Obtention du chemin complet de la base de données
        NSArray *documentPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *documentsDir = [documentPaths objectAtIndex:0];
        databasePath = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:databaseName];
    }
    return self;
}
```

**EDIT**

And my query is executed like this :

```
-(NSMutableDictionary *)getList:(NSString*)typeOfRequest{

sqlite3 *database;
const char *sqlStatement = [typeOfRequest UTF8String];
NSMutableDictionary *aromaArray = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
if(sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {

    sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement;

    //Compilation de la requete et verification du succes
    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlStatement, -1, &compiledStatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {

        NSDictionary *dictionary = [self indexByColumnName:compiledStatement]; // Creation d'un dictionnaire des noms de colonnes
        NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

        while(sqlite3_step(compiledStatement) == SQLITE_ROW) {

            char *tab = (char*)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, [[dictionary objectForKey:nil] intValue]);
            NSString *finalUpperCase = [[NSString stringWithUTF8String:tab] capitalizedString];
            if (finalUpperCase != nil && finalUpperCase.length >0 && !([finalUpperCase isEqualToString:@"Null"])) {
                [array addObject:finalUpperCase];
            }
        }
        aromaArray = [self getDictionnary:array];
    }
    else {
        NSAssert1(0, @"Erreur :. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
    }
    sqlite3_finalize(compiledStatement); // Finalise la requete et libere le statement
}
else {
    NSAssert(0, @"Erreur d'ouverture de la base de donnees");
}
sqlite3_close(database);
return aromaArray;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you included `info_max.sqlite3` in your target?

Comment: By target you mean this : http://imgur.com/xkVXisB ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes Xcode its a mess and it's Derived Data keep references of files, so sometimes you need to clear the Product and Run it again.

1. Quit XCode
2. Go to derived data's folder, delete them (also from trash).
3. Open XCode clean project and try to build it again

For insert and Update queries that is not enough:

### Insert and Update Queries

When you copy this file to bundle (target) you have this file only read-only. To make it readable and be able to make insert queries follow the solution below:

This code creates a writable copy of the bundled default database in the application Documents directory. Put it on `application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` on `appDelegate` and now you will be able to test your queries:

```
// First, test for existence.
BOOL success;

NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

NSError *error;
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

NSString *writableDBPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"info_max.sqlite3"];
success = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:writableDBPath];

if (success) return;

// The writable database does not exist, so copy the default to the appropriate location.
NSString *defaultDBPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"info_max.sqlite3"];
success = [fileManager copyItemAtPath:defaultDBPath toPath:writableDBPath error:&error];
if (!success)
{
    NSAssert1(0, @"Failed to create writable database file with message '%@'.", [error localizedDescription]);
}
```

Comment: Are you making a connection to your database anywhere? Remember to add sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &database)

Comment: Exit Xcode and delete your derived data and clean your project. Delete also the app from your device, run it again and give me feedback.

Comment: Thats weird because I am working with that kind of application right now. Try to NSLog your query if there is something wrong with it

Comment: I did 3 NSLOG : NSLog(@"%@", databasePath);
    NSLog(@"%@", databaseName);
    NSLog(@"%@", typeOfRequest);
And the First two re (null) ..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62420/discussion-between-erid-bardhaj-and-nicolas-charvoz-kurzawa).

Answer (score 0):

You must have to also try move that Database(sqlite) file to out of project directory and add it again and clear all cache data.

it is work for me.